# Where is the "notify me when in stock" data saved in which table?

Tags: stock, product-alert, stock-alert

Hi I am trying to see where is "notify me in stock alert " data saved to which table.
Moreover, default Magento customer profile should include the item alert list or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `install` method in `Magento\ProductAlert\Setup\Recurring` you're probably looking for the table named `product_alert_stock`.

Comment: thanks! I believe this is the table that I am looking for